# What citation style is this?

Tags: citing

I need the following bibliography style I looked up different citation styles but I could not find something similar.

In the text, the citations are marked with a footnote (should no be longer than one line).

> Eg: For books we have². For journal articles we have³. For an online
>   resource, we have the following style$^4$. (I don't know how to use
>   LaTeX on TeX.StackExchange :D).
>
> ---
>
> ²Einstein, A.; Bohr, N.: Some epic book (1920), S. 20-25.
>
> ³Euler, L.: Some epic math equations (1770).
>
> ${}^4$Solid Snake: How to clone your brother (2003).

In the Bibliography, it should look like the following (without so much space after the boldface part and the non-boldface part.

> **Einstein, A.; Bohr, N.: Some epic book (1920)**
>
> Einstein, A.; Bohr, N.: Some epic book, Springer Verlag, New York,
>   1920
>
> **Euler, L.: Some epic math equations (1770)**
>
> Euler, L.: Some epic math equations, in: International Conference in
>   advanced Epicness, Vol. 31, S. 641-651, 1770
>
> **Solid Snake: How to clone your brother (2003)**
>
> Solid Snake: How to clone your brother,
>   https://www.SolidSnakeBlog.com, 2003, Zugriff 01.01.2007

The URL should not be marked like in my post. It should be displayed as plain text. Zugriff 01.01.2017 is just the date at which I accessed the resource. and S. 20-25 is the German version of p. 20-25.

> **Question**: It would be helpful if someone could help me out on this weird
>   citation style. The people from the institution that forces me to use
>   his citation style said that I should rather use Word (for which they
>   have a template that does this weird citation style) because LaTeX
>   would not support such a citation style. I am pretty sure LaTeX can
>   even handle this but I could not find anything similar to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of a readily available style that gives exactly the output you need. The combination of author-title citations with year is quite unusual as far as pre-built styles in LaTeX are concerned. Here is a start with [`biblatex-ext`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext).

Most things used here should have names that tell you more or less what they do. If it is not clear what the commands do, a search in the [`biblatex` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) and the [`biblatex-ext` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-ext/biblatex-ext.pdf) should hopefully clear things up.

There are probably a few more details that need to be fixed. [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864) is a great post to get started with those.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=ext-authortitle,
  labeldateparts,
  giveninits, uniquename=init,
  introcite=plain,
  autocite=footnote,
]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}
\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{sortname}

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareDelimFormat*{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat[textcite]{nametitledelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{#1}
\DeclareDelimFormat{titleyeardelim}{\addspace}

\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{cite:labeldate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
         \printtext[\blx@delimcontext labeldate]{%
           \printlabeldate}}}}}
\makeatother

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\printnames{labelname}%
     \setunit*{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:title}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{titleyeardelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate}}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{bbx@introcite}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\introcitepunct}{\newline}

\renewbibmacro*{pubinstorg+location+date}[1]{%
  \printlist{#1}%
  \setunit*{\publocdelim}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\locdatedelim}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem\autocite[380-381]{sigfridsson}
Ipsum\autocite{worman}
Dolor\autocite{geer}
Sit\autocite{nussbaum}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Example output similar in style to the desiderata in the question.]

Comment: If anything is unclear about the code above after a short look at the two linked documentations, please don't hesitate to comment. If you need additional changes to the code, I would however, like to suggest you ask a new question (about one *specific* issue: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864, questions like that are usually more generally applicable and more useful for a wider audience than one question where your style is coded in its entirety).

Comment: I will try to incorporate your solution. I will accept it as soon as I am able to implement it.

Comment: could you add your biblatex-examples.bib, such that I can see what you did there :D

Comment: @MachineLearner `biblatex-examples.bib` is part of every `biblatex` installation. If you can't find it on your computer (type `kpsewhich biblatex-examples.bib` into the terminal/command line), you can get it from CTAN http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/bibtex/bib/biblatex/biblatex-examples.bib or view it on GitHub: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/master/bibtex/bib/biblatex/biblatex-examples.bib

Comment: @ Thank you for the hint. I cannot compile your code. I tried it on overleaf. I also added the biblatex-examples.bib.

Comment: @MachineLearner Overleaf are running an older version of TeX live that does not have `biblatex-ext` installed yet (and an outdated version of `biblatex`). Is there any chance you can compile your document on an up-to-date local system (MikTeX or TeX live)?

Comment: I tried your code on a local Miktex installation with texmaker. But I get the following error `This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6960 64-bit) The top-level auxiliary file: citation_test.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file citation_test.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file citation_test.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file citation_test.aux (There were 3 error messages)

Process exited with error(s)`. I am Using Pdflatex>Biblatex>2xPdflatex->View pdf as the order of compilation.

Comment: @MachineLearner The code needs Biber instead of BibTeX. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864  for help with getting your editor to run Biber instead of BibTeX.